# WebAPI AttributeRouting with version number as parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, attributerouting

I am trying to set up a route to my MVC controller action with the following template:

```
[Route("app/{appId:length(20)}/validate/{version}")]
```

The idea is that the resulting URL would then look something like this:
(I'm adding a space to make the localhost url try not resolve...)

> http:/ /localhost:2642/api/update/v1/app/6A6EE0B355C34DBFB381/validate/1.0.0.0

The problem I have is that this would give me a 404 error.

If I remove the Route attribute and use the built-in MVC routing, it works. The url then is:

> http:/ /localhost:2642/api/external/CheckForUpdate?appId=6A6EE0B355C34DBFB381&version=1.0.0.0

This should work since I know Nuget has got versions in their URL's, but I think they use the built-in MVC router.

I also tried to add the :regex() markup in the template for the route so validate the string format, but that didn't work. If I pass in a normal string or a value such as 1_0_0_0 it works. Thing is I don't want to go through the effort to manipulate the version string before sending it to the api and then in the api itself.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make your routing attribute

```
[Route("app/{appId:length(20)}/validate/{version:regex(^([1-9]\\d+|[0-7])(\\.\\d{1,3}){0,3}$)}")]
```

and make sure you accept the parameters in the method

```
public Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(string appId, string version)
{
    //magic
}
```

then in the web.config, system.webServer > handlers section  change the `*.` to `*`

```
<add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```

to

```
<add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```

and also make sure

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
```

exists in `<system.webServer>`

Comment: I took out the regex part for now as that seems to also give the 404 result. It's not the end of the world though as it does work now.

Comment: I tested it and it worked, if you put more details of the method signature and webserver section of web.config something may stand out